# ASP.NET MVC + Unity 2.0: lazy loading dependency properties?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

What i want Unity 2.0 to do is to instantiate what i need by getting the new properties from the configurations all the time, a bit hard to explain.

Basically this is what i want to do:

global.asax

```
container.RegisterType<IBackendWrapper, BackendWrapper>(new InjectionProperty("UserIdent", (HttpContext.Current.Session == null ? new UserIdent() : HttpContext.Current.Session["UserIdent"] as UserIdent)));
```

What i want this to do is that whenever someone needs an IBackendWrapper, unity should then get the Session["UserIdent"] and populate the BackendWrapper with that information.

Right now unity only loads this information once and it always returns a new UserIdent even when i have an User ident stored in the session. Is there a way to get this behavior in Unity 2.0? or is it supported by another IoC framework like NInject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's supported in Unity. You need to register `UserIdent` with an `InjectionFactory` so it's evaluated on each resolve.

```
container
    .RegisterType<UserIdent>(new InjectionFactory(c =>
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session == null
            ? new UserIdent()
            : HttpContext.Current.Session["UserIdent"] as UserIdent;
    }));

container
    .RegisterType<IBackendWrapper, BackendWrapper>(
        new InjectionProperty("UserIdent", new ResolvedParameter<UserIdent>())
    );
```

The way you were registering it, `HttpContext.Current.Session` was being evaluated at the time you did the registration which is presumably in Global.asax before your session was set up.